# Strange rounding behaviour with BigDecimal?

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

What would be printed to console and why?

1.

```
BigDecimal BigDecimalNum = new BigDecimal("0.0774");
System.out.println(BigDecimalNum.doubleValue() * 100.00);
```

2.

```
BigDecimal BigDecimalNum2 = new BigDecimal("0.0774");   
System.out.println(BigDecimalNum2.multiply(new BigDecimal("100.00")));
```

Comment: Rather than make us guess or run it ourselves, why haven't you said what's being printed and why you're surprised by it?

Comment: What would be printed to console? Come on, you can try that yourself, can't you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The results on my machine are:

```
7.739999999999999
7.740000
```

This doesn't surprise me at all. In the second case we're dealing entirely with BigDecimal, and always multiplying - there's no reason for anything to go wrong.

In the first case you're converting the BigDecimal to a double, so your code is *effectively*

```
double d = 0.0774;
System.out.println(d * 100.0);
```

The value 0.0774 can't be exactly represented as a `double`, hence the discrepancy.

This has nothing to do with `BigDecimal`, and everything to do with `double`. You should almost *never* be converting between `BigDecimal` and `double` though - the kind of values which are appropriate for use in `BigDecimal` are almost always *inappropriate* to represent as `double` values.

Comment: What the problem with 0.0774 being as double? I don`t see any problem. 

double d = 0.0774;
System.out.println(d);
d = 7.74;
System.out.println(d);

Giving me the desired result.

Comment: @dmitril: It can't be stored exactly as a double. The closest double value to 0.0774 is just a bit less than 0.0774. Read up on other related questions - I can't add much now, but will come back to this later on if you're still confused. Read http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx (It's written about .NET, but the exact same principles apply in Java. Both use IEEE-754 binary floating point numbers.)

Comment: Thanks, now it is clear. I just used to C/C++ where you can do such kind of math without holding in mind such stuff.

Comment: @dmitril: You really can't. You'd get the same effect in C at least for the actual values. How those values are formatted by the C standard library is a different matter, but you really shouldn't expect all decimal vales to be represented exactly in binary floating point types.